# Extending list in python by appending empty values

Tags: python, list, dataframe

1. I have list containing, let say 7 values . now I want to extend that list by adding 3 empty strings.
   for example:

   ```py
   actual_list =[1,2,3,4,5,6,7]

   expected_list = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,,,,]
   ```
2. then I will convert this list into a pandas series.
3. after this I want to assign this series to another pandas series  having only NAN's as elements.

Is there any way to do step 1? I have tried step 2 and step 3, but failed to understanding the first step.

Comment: let me know if I was able to explain my query

Comment: Do you mean `[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,'','','']`

Comment: yes , I meant that only

Comment: did you try `actual_list.extend(['']*3)`?

Comment: no, I have just started with python so don't have much idea. will try this one

Answer (score 0):

Step 1 is straight forward as follows:

```
>>> actual_list=actual_list + ["", "", ""]
>>> actual_list
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, '', '', '']
>>>
```

Comment: `l = l + something` is a very bad idea. Either use `l += something` or `l.extend(something)`. To know why read this https://www.python-course.eu/python3_list_manipulation.php#Extending-and-Appending-Lists-with-the-'+'-Operator

Answer (score 0):

You could use the `.extend` method of list.

Example: (should work as is)

```
def custom_extend(l: list, n=3, pattern=None):
    l_= l.copy()
    l_.extend([pattern for x in range(n)])
    return pd.Series(l_)
```

```
>>> print(custom_extend([1,2,3,4,5,6,7], n=3, pattern=None))
0    1.0
1    2.0
2    3.0
3    4.0
4    5.0
5    6.0
6    7.0
7    NaN
8    NaN
9    NaN
dtype: float64
```

Comment: `l.extend(['' for x in range(3)])` to match OP's expected output.